# ¿Cómo puedo fijar este error: could not convert string to float: '1,448.94'?

Tags: python, pandas

En el siguiente `DataFrame`, los valores (1,531.20,...) son importados con el formato `object`.

Intento convertirlos al tipo `float`, aplicando el método `.astype(float)`.

```
# Create DF from dict of lists/ndarrays
df = pd.DataFrame({'MSCI' : ['1,448.94', '1,480.57', '1,495.18', '1,531.20', '1,532.28'],
                       'Date' : ['2012-07-09','2012-07-10', '2012-07-11', '2012-07-12', '2012-07-13']})

df.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
df["MSCI"] = df.MSCI.astype(float)
df.info()
```

Me devuelve el error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,448.94'

Agradeceré sugerencias para subsanar este error-

Por otro lado, ¿podría de alguna manera conseguir que en la importación estos números ya vengan convertidos al formato `float`?.

En la importación utilizo `pd.read_csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que los valores que tienes no son `float`, si te fijas tienen "dos comas", `1,448.94`.

Si suponemos que realmente la coma, es un separador del millar, podríamos coger todos los valores, eliminarles la coma y convertirlos a `float`,

```
import pandas as pd

# Create DF from dict of lists/ndarrays
df = pd.DataFrame({'MSCI' : ['1,448.94', '1,480.57', '1,495.18', '1,531.20', '1,532.28'],
                       'Date' : ['2012-07-09','2012-07-10', '2012-07-11', '2012-07-12', '2012-07-13']})

df.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
msci_vals = df['MSCI'].values
for i in range(len(msci_vals)):
  myVal = msci_vals[i].replace(",", "")
  msci_vals[i] = float(myVal)
```

Así ahora tienes una lista con todos los valores del `dataframe` de tipo flotante.

Espero haber sido de ayuda, ¡cualquier cosa nos dices!

Comment: Gracias. Añado una línea al bucle for:  df.iloc[i,0] = myVal